# HTML / CSS - How to make overlay video text completely responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am creating a website for a friend and I have a video landing screen for the homepage. I want to simply put text over the video, on the very centre - which I have managed to do.

However when using the developer tools and changing between viewports, I see that when viewed on a phone, the overlay text is pushed way down the page... even further down depending on how narrow the phone is.

Here is the CSS code for the overlay writing...

```html
#MainTitle
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: 'Original Surfer', cursive;
    color: darkblue;
    font-size: 18pt;
}
```

The video is displaying perfectly, but the overlay text is proving difficult. Please help!

Comment: you can try to reset font-size according to screen width: `font-size:calc(10px + 2vw);` if your question is about this. *tune the values to your needs*.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I have the code hosted here if you want to have a look, sorry that I havent described it too well - https://github.com/bmcgowan94/AdventureOneSurfSchool

Comment: @brianmcgowan this is too much to sort through. Can you not give us a minimal reproducible example? It will help you get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this style to videoDiv, it will be like this:

`<div id="videoDiv" style="position: relative;margin-top: 80px;">`

then remove `padding-top: 80px;` from `#myVideo`.